# Error when connecting to wunderground API

Tags: pandas, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape wind speed data for different UK weather stations using the site wunderground. I assume they have an API, I just have a hard to connecting to it.
Here's the XHR link I use:

```
https://api.weather.com/v1/location/EGNV:9:GB/observations/historical.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&units=e&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150131
```

This is the data I would like. The table in the bottom for wind speed:

```
https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/gb/darlington/EGNV/date/2015-1
```

My code, pretty simple: I first load the headers, my function get_data gets me the response in json format.

In my main I append the data to a dataframe and print it.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib 
from urllib.request import urlopen

headers = {
    ':authority': 'api.weather.com',
    #':path': '/v1/location/EGNV:9:GB/observations/historical.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&units=e&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150131',
    ':scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,da;q=0.7',
    'origin': 'https://www.wunderground.com',
    #'apiKey': '6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e',
    'referer': 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/gb/darlington/EGNV/date/2015-1',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36'

}

def get_data(response):
    df = response.json()

    return df 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    date = pd.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

    api_key = "6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e"
    start_date = "20150101"
    end_date = "20150131"

    urls = [
    "https://api.weather.com/v1/location/EGNV:9:GB/observations/historical.json?apiKey="+ api_key +"&units=e&startDate="+start_date+"&endDate="+end_date+""
    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for url in urls:  
        res = requests.get(url, headers= headers)
        data = get_data(res)
        df = df.append(data) 
    print(df)
```

The error I get:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.weather.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/location/EGNV:9:GB/observations/historical.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&units=e&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150131 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Update:
Even when without trying to connect to the API, but by scraping the page using BS4, I still get denied access. Not sure why, and how they can detect my scraper?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

If I add verify = False in my requests.get() I manage to go around the error.